# salvar sequência de fibonacci em C

Tags: c

Eu preciso fazer um programa que guarde em arquivo os 100 primeiros números da sequência de Fibonacci. Eu consegui fazer a sequência direitinho, só que na hora do programa salvar o arquivo aparece no arquivo só o número "695895453".

Como que eu faço para salvar todos os números?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

 int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    FILE * teste;

    int a, b, aux, i;

    a = 1;
    b = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        aux = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = aux;

        printf(" %d ,", aux);
    }


    if((teste = fopen("teste.txt","w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro de abertura! \n");
    }

    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            aux = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = aux;

            fprintf(teste,"%d" ,aux);
            fclose(teste);
        }


        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Você primeiro imprime os primeiros 64 membros da sequencia de Fibonacci e logo a seguir grava os 64 membros **seguintes** da sequencia. Se quiser gravar os 64 primeiros reinicialize as variáveis `a` e `b`.

Comment: Na realidade deveria ser `a = 0;` e `b = 1;` e estes são os dois primeiros elementos da sequencia e portanto devem ser gravados primeiro e depois gravados os 62 elementos seguintes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não estás a indicar a criação de uma nova linha. Inclui o valor `\n` na instrução `fprintf` para criar uma nova linha.

```
(...)
fprintf(teste,"%d\n" ,aux);
(...)
```

Atenção, noutro ponto: Convém só fechar o ficheiro depois de terminar o processo de escrita. A instrução `fclose(teste)` deve ser colocado fora do ciclo `for`.

Com estas alterações no teu código, na minha máquina (não é Windows) funciona sem espinhas.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    FILE * teste;

    long a, b, aux, i;

    a = 1;
    b = 0;

    if((teste = fopen("teste.txt","w")) == NULL) {
        printf("Erro de abertura! \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
        aux = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = aux;

        fprintf(teste,"%ld\n" ,aux);
        printf(" %ld ,", aux);
    }

    fclose(teste);
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Não funcionou, continua imprimindo só o número "695895453" no arquivo.

Comment: Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Windows. Eu coloquei o fclose(teste) fora do loop mas agora está imprimindo uns números negativos e não a sequência completa de fibonacci. Será que isso é lixo armazenado no programa?

Comment: Para windows a string é `\r\n`.

Comment: Eu mudei e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Por um lado não estás a reiniciar as variávies a e b. Por isso, o ficheiro estás a registar, nao os primeiros 64 numeros da sequência mas os 2ºs.

O "lixo" vem do tamanho do numero. A sequencia cresce muito rápidamente e em poucas iterações ultrapassas o maxInt. Tenta mudar para "long" e no printf e fprints o `%d` para `%ld`.

Comment: Mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: Agora sim! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Seu programa não está bom. Tem um livro sobre C? Pensou sobre isso? Leu alguma tabela sore a sequência?

- Tivesse pensado nisso e procurado por uma tabela e veria por exemplo em [Os primeiros 100 números na sequência de Fibonacci](http://www.educ.fc.ul.pt/icm/icm99/icm41/os100.htm) que o último número de que precisa é 10610209857723 que tem 14 dígitos
- E assim não ficaria surpreso por ver valores negativos usando um `int` cujo máximo é bem conhecido: `INT_MAX` = **+2147483647** que tem só 10 dígitos. E se pensar a respeito vai ver também que a sequência começa em `1` então todos os números são positivos e não há sentido em usar `int` que tem sinal
- evite esse tipo (comum) de construção

```
 if((teste = fopen("teste.txt","w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Erro de abertura! \n");
    }

    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            aux = a + b;
            a = b;
            b = aux;

            fprintf(teste,"%d" ,aux);
            fclose(teste);
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

- Note que o `return` está dentro da cláusula do `if()` e não fora, e se o `fopen()` falhar o programa não passa pelo `return`.
- entenda que se não conseguir abrir o arquivo não tem razão para continuar com o programa, já que o objetivo é gravar o arquivo. Faça o simples e retorne.
- ao gerar os números grave no arquivo ao mesmo tempo ou vai perder os valores que não gravou. Claro que pode reiniciar `a` e `b` e usar outro loop mas seria pouco inteligente
- declare variáveis de controle DENTRO do loop. Levou muitos anos para o comitê arrumar isso na linguagem, mas faz 30 anos. É muito importante para você mesmo reduzir o escopo --- *scope*, vida --- das variáveis. em especial umas com nomes singelos como `a`,`b` e `aux`.

#### Um exemplo

Copiando de seu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

 int main()
 {
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"portuguese");
    FILE * teste = fopen("teste.txt","w");
    if( teste == NULL)
    {   printf("Erro de abertura! \n");
        return 0;
    }

    unsigned long long a = 1;
    unsigned long long  b = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        unsigned long long aux = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = aux;
        printf("%4i%15llu\n", 1+i,aux);
        fprintf(teste, "%15llu\n", aux);
    };  // for()
    fclose(teste);
    return 0;
};  // main()
```

**Mostra na tela**

```
   1              1
   2              1
   3              2
   4              3
   5              5
   ...
  62  4052739537881
  63  6557470319842
  64 10610209857723
```

**E grava no disco um número por linha**

```
              1
              1
              2
              3
              5
...
  4052739537881
  6557470319842
 10610209857723
```